# What is the maximal torus in the Lorentz group $O(m,n)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-theory, matrices, lie-groups

I'm close to certain it's just the product of the maximal tori of $O(m)$ and $O(n)$, but I can't quite prove it. I've tried the following:

$\newcommand{\mattwo}[4]{\left(\begin{array}{cc}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{array}\right)}$

Any element of the Lorentz group can be decomposed into

$$\mattwo{P}{0}{0}{Q}\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}$$

Where $P, Q$ are orthogonal block matrices, $P\in O(m)$, $Q\in O(n)$. So we can definitely pick maximal tori in $P$ and $Q$ (call them $T_1, T_2$), and $T_1\times T_2$ will definitely be a torus in $O(m,n)$.

To prove it's maximal, assume not. I try to find a contradiction using the fact that tori must be abelian. That's where things get a little ugly.

Take an arbitrary element $\mattwo{P'}{0}{0}{Q'}\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}\in O(m,n)$ and supposed for the sake of contradiction that it lives in a larger torus containing $T_1\times T_2$. Then it must commute with every element in $T_1\times T_2$. This means for every $P\in T_1, Q\in T_2$, we must have

$$\mattwo{P}{0}{0}{Q}\mattwo{P'}{0}{0}{Q'}\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}=\mattwo{P'}{0}{0}{Q'}\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}\mattwo{P}{0}{0}{Q}$$

Knowing that $\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}$ is symmetric, we can say $$\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}=\mattwo{X_1}{X_2}{X_2^T}{X_3}$$

Which multiplies out to

$$\mattwo{PP'X_1}{PP'X_2}{QQ'X_2^T}{QQ'X_3}=\mattwo{P'X_1P}{P'X_2Q}{Q'X_2^TP}{Q'X_3Q}$$

and this gives us

\begin{align*}
PP'X_1&=P'X_1P\\
PP'X_2&=P'X_2Q\\
QQ'X_2^T&=Q'X_2^TP\\
QQ'X_3&=Q'X_3Q\\
\end{align*}

which must hold for every $P\in T_1, Q\in T_2$.

This seems like it would be a strict enough set of four equations that would force $\exp\mattwo{0}{X}{X^T}{0}=\mattwo{1}{0}{0}{1}$, which would then force $P'\in T_1$, $Q'\in T_2$, but I can't for the life of me get the four equations to imply that.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that $O(m)\times O(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $O(m,n)$, and any maximal compact subgroup is [conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup#Existence_and_uniqueness) to this one. A maximal torus, being compact, will therefore be contained in a conjugate of $O(m)\times O(n)$. Hence it will be conjugate to your $T_1\times T_2$.